# Group By View Broken

Tags: 2013, migration, custom

I have a Custom 'Cascading Drop Down' Control that I migrated from a 2007 Solution to 2013. The control / logic works properly except all of the Migrated views that contained this Control as a Group are broken.

I have tried to drill down using SharePoint Manager but no modifications to the View / CAML will work. There is lots of data in this field but I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot. Any suggestions or is there anything wrong with this xml?

```
<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"><FieldRef Name="Engineering_x0020__x0026__x0020_Construction_x0020_Level_x0020_1" /></GroupBy>
```

Comment: can you rebuild/reconfigure it from the UI?

Comment: I tried creating the view from scratch and stripping away all fields except the Custom one I'm grouping. All the values even show up in the header but the view shows no results